# Add a placeholder text to the TextField

Tags: unity

This is my TextField:

```
EditorGUILayout.TextField("Placeholder Text", textfield, GUILayout.Height(35));
```

How can I add a placeholder text in my textfield that will be removed when I want to type in the field?

Comment: @Bálint : The OP asks for a placeholder in Custom editor function. Not the UGUI system.

Comment: @Hellium Sorry, I mixed up 2 separate questions

Answer (score 1):

@Thomas Mathieson approach is close to the answer, but I'd like to add more. With this example the text field value will return to the default Placeholder text if it is empty:

```
private string defaultPlaceHolder = "Insert Text: ";
public string textFieldValue;

textFieldValue = EditorGUILayout.TextField(textFieldValue == string.Empty ? defaultPlaceHolder : textFieldValue, GUILayout.Height(35));
```

To avoid having the Placeholder value on Play mode, you could either add more logic, or just set the value to **string.Empty** if the value is equal to the Placeholder's.

Additionally, **EditorGUILayout.TextField** has an overload that takes a **GUIStyle** as a parameter, with that you can change the placeholder color to a more gray one, to give that illusion that it's a placeholder. I just have used **GUIStyle** for textures, so I don't know exactly how to change the text color, but, you could check by tweaking values on the inspector, just serialize a GUIStyle, and assign that to the **TextField**, something like this:

```
public GUIStyle textStyle;
public string textFieldValue;
private string defaultPlaceHolder = "Insert Text: ";


textFieldValue = EditorGUILayout.TextField(
                "Text Field Label: ",
                textFieldValue == string.Empty ? defaultPlaceHolder : textFieldValue,
                textStyle);
```

Check [TextField's Overloads](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.TextField.html) for more reference. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing as OP and didn't find an answer here, so here's my solution:

Imports:

```
using System;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
```

Simplest implementation:

```
string TextField(string text, string placeholder) {
    var newText = EditorGUILayout.TextField(text);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) {
        var guiColor = GUI.color;
        GUI.color = Color.grey;
        EditorGUI.LabelField(GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect(), placeholder);
        GUI.color = guiColor;
    }
    return newText;
}
```

Implementation supporting both TextField and TextArea using generic method, as well as placing Label at the same spot where Text is rendered:

```
string TextField(string text, string placeholder) {
    return TextInput(text, placeholder);
}

string TextArea(string text, string placeholder) {
    return TextInput(text, placeholder, area: true);
}

private string TextInput(string text, string placeholder, bool area = false) {
    var newText = area ? EditorGUILayout.TextArea(text) : EditorGUILayout.TextField(text);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text.Trim())) {
        const int textMargin = 2;
        var guiColor = GUI.color;
        GUI.color = Color.grey;
        var textRect = GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect();
        var position = new Rect(textRect.x + textMargin, textRect.y, textRect.width, textRect.height);
        EditorGUI.LabelField(position, placeholder);
        GUI.color = guiColor;
    }
    return newText;
}
```

Usage:

```
string text = String.Empty;
string area = String.Empty;

void OnGUI() {
    text = TextField(text, "Field placeholder");
    area = TextArea(area, "Area placeholder");
}
```

Here's how it looks in Unity:

[image: Text with placeholder visual representation]

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to test this but you could try:

```
//In the script initialisation
string textfield = "Placeholder text";
//In the OnGui function
textfield = EditorGUILayout.TextField(textfield,GUILayout.Height(35));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
public string inputContent = "";
public string placeholder = "Text here...";

private void OnGUI() {
  // Draw TextArea
  inputContent = EditorGUILayout.TextArea(inputContent, GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true), GUILayout.ExpandHeight(true));
  // Draw Placeholder
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputContent)) {
    Rect pos = new Rect(GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect());
    GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle
    {
      alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft,
      padding = new RectOffset(3, 0, 2, 0),
      fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
      normal =
      {
        textColor = Color.grey
      }
    };
    EditorGUI.LabelField(pos, placeholder, style);
  }
}
```

That's what it will look like:

[image]